# Escape special characters in FMDB iOS query

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite, special-characters, fmdb

I wrote a query with arguments in FMDB using ? mark symbol.I want to get details of users who has any of info in the list(hope i can give different info separated by commas in "in" statement in sql). Since my arguments having special symbols, It is throwing error. How to escape there special symbols. I tried different methods but none worked yet

My code is like:

```
FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"select details from user where info in(?)",infoList];
while([results next])
    {...}
```

Info is a string combined by different string seperated by commas.For example:

> 'C-note','Cuban missile crisis, the','cubbyhole','I Love Lucy','I'm a Celebrity ... Get me Out of Here!','Iacocca, Lee','-iana','Ivy League, the'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a single `?` with an `in` clause unless you only bind a single value. It doesn't work for a list of values.

Since `infoList` is an array of string values, one option is to add a `?` for each value in the list.

```
NSMutableString *query = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"select details from user where info in ("];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < infoList.count; i++) {
    if (i) {
        [query appendString:@","];
    }
    [query appendString:@"?"];
}
[query appendString:@")"];
FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:query withArgumentsInArray:infoList];
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. The issue here is that infoList is dynamically generating and I cant say where the special symbol may comes. And it is available in an Array also, If we can process some other way. I saw some function like ` [db executeQuery:<#(NSString *)#> withArgumentsInArray:<#(NSArray *)#>] ` .is it usable in this case?

Comment: I updated the answer given that `infoList`` is an array of strings.

Comment: I checked with NSString withformat:] . It is working fine. I will check with this and let you know. Sorry for the late reply.